# Can I push to a branch after I made a merge request?

Tags: git, gitlab, pull-request

Is it okay to push to a branch after a merge request has been made?

When the branch actually gets merged into the master branch, does it take the new pushes (made after the merge request has been made) into account?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Yes.**

The merge request wil update itself to reflect any new commits pushed since it was created, until you finally merge it.

When you do merge, every commit on the source branch which is not yet on the destination branch will be detected and merged in, regardless of whether it was initially in the merge request or later added to it.

---

Anecdotically (since it was not specifically in your question) you could even force-push (`git push -f`) to a branch after a merge request has been created, it would update its state accordingly.

**The "point of no return" here is the merging of the request, not its creation.**